# asks for $scope to fool the BC controller module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, comments

In the source code of the directive ngSwitch and FromController you can see this comment:

```
// asks for $scope to fool the BC controller module
```

what kind of cheating is it?  why is it used?

#### [ngSwitch Source Line](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngSwitch.js#L136)

```
    // asks for $scope to fool the BC controller module
    controller: ['$scope', function ngSwitchController() {
     this.cases = {};
    }] ...
```

#### [FormController Soruce Line](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/form.js#L53)

```
//asks for $scope to fool the BC controller module
FormController.$inject = ['$element', '$attrs', '$scope', '$animate'];
function FormController(element, attrs, $scope, $animate) {  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [BC controller module](https://gist.github.com/vojtajina/1649788) is shorthand for `Backward Compatability`.

> Load this module to enable old-style controllers, where controller and scope are mixed together.
>
> This module decorates Angular's $controller service:
>
> - if given controller does not ask for $scope, it instantiates it in old-way
> - if given controller does ask for $scope, instantiation is delegated to default $controller
>     service.
>
>   This also allows migrating apps step by step.

So, the default angular modules always ask for the `$scope` reference even if they do not intend to use it, to avoid being instantiated for BC.